# how would i find all locations of symlinks that point to a particular path or file?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, symbolic-link

I have a file system where one or more symlinks exist to a file.  Is there a way to go thru each file and determine where all the symlinks that point to it on the file system are?

OS is Ubuntu 9.10 Linux

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: linux - ubuntu 9.10 to be exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use good old `find` with the `-lname` switch:

```
find / -lname '/path/to/linked/file' 2> /dev/null
```

For a more intricate approach, you can use the inode number of the file (retrieve from `ls -i <file>`):

```
find / -follow -inum 123456 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: this has the limitation that it only matches a symlink with that exact filename (or pattern).  it wouldn't catch a symlink to a symlink to that file.  (so if symB points to fileA and symC points to symB, and you run this command looking for fileA, it'll find symB but not symC.)

Comment: True, but I'm just following the criteria he's given us.

Comment: just sayin'.  nice addition tho.  :)